# Coffeescript object creation validation

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is it possible to cancel object creation in coffeescript if certain criteria are not met?  I want to do something like this:

```
class Foo
  constructor:(@name) ->
    return false if !name

withName = new Foo("bar") #withName -> obj
noName = new Foo #noName -> false
```

But with that code the object is still created. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the validation conditions at the call site, inside the constructor is far to late.

Take a look at the compiled javascript for the class:

```
 Foo = (function() {

    function Foo(name) {
      this.name = name;
      if (!name) return false;
    }

    return Foo;

  })();

  withName = new Foo("bar");

  noName = new Foo;

}).call(this);
```

And it should be a little more clear why it doesn't work.

The `new` keyword happens **before** the constructor is called.

How about something like this (NOT TESTED)

```
runIf = (someVar, someDelegate) ->
    someDelegate someVar if someVar 

withName = runIf "bar", -> new Foo("bar") 
noName = runIf null, -> new Foo()
```

Which compiles down to:

```
runIf = function(someVar, someDelegate) {
    if (someVar) return someDelegate(someVar);
  };

  withName = runIf("bar", function() {
    return new Foo("bar");
  });

  noName = runIf(null, function() {
    return new Foo();
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do this is to throw an exception from the constructor:

```
class Foo
  constructor:(@name) ->
    throw new Error('Name must be specified') if !name
```

However, as a stylistic matter, exceptions aren't commonly used this way in JS.